# Nuget Pack is getting wrong dependencies for my project

Tags: nuget

I have a project in visual studio and I am having  set to true for the build.

My packages.config looks like this

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

but the returned nupkg ends up with the following dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="1.0.0" />
  <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" />
  <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" />
  <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" />
  <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.1.0" />
  <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.1.0" />
</dependencies>
```

In visual studio as seen in the packages.config i had a reference to Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 2.1.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin has its dependencies set to >2.0.0 so I am wondering how come Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth is ignored for my packages dependencies.

This causes my deployment to fail because it fetches the 2.0 of oauth and not 2.1 as my package depend on.

Is this how its supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has satisfied the package dependencies based on the info it has available (choosing version 2.0.0 as you've seen). You can be more specific about package versions you require by using the `allowedVersions` attribute in *packages.config*, in this case, setting

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" allowedVersions="[2.1,3)" targetFramework="net45" />
```

which specifies to use at least version 2.1.0 of *Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth*, but possibly also 2.2.x and up to 2.9.y, but not 3.0

That *might* cause incompatibilities with *Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin*, though, which will need resolving separately.

Comment: Ye, I manually added more info to my package.config and added assembly bindings and things work.